# How can I exclude and include in the same grep?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm writing a shell script that finds occurences a string ($string) of a certain filetype ($ext) in the current working directory ($cwd).

I also want to exclude all files that contain a certain string ("mbundle").

How would I amend what I have, to do that?

```
grep -nrwl $string --include=\*."$ext" "$cwd"
```

*Sorry, I'm still pretty new to grep and regex/globbing patterns etc*

Comment: Using pipes will probably be your best friend. `grep #something | grep #something`. You would have 2 commands chained, but its still pure grep :)

Comment: I'm going to try that out. I'll post an answer if it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Allendar, I've tried several variations and can't get this to work. For example: `grep -rv "mbundle" "$cwd" |  grep -nrwl $string --include=\*."$ext" "$cwd"` and `grep -exclude=\mbundle\ |  grep -nrwl $string --include=\*."$ext" "$cwd"`... Thoughts?

Comment: Are the two different patterns on the same line, or just anywhere in the file?

Comment: The "mbundle" exclude pattern is for the filename -- the other is for anywhere in the remaining files. So basically I want to search for a term anywhere in files, and exclude results from certain files.

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE) option then you can use `negative lookahead` to avoid matching `mbundle`:

```
grep -P -nrwl "(?!.*?mbundle)$string" --include=\*."$ext" "$cwd"
```

Comment: Mine doesn't support it. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Which system are you on? Is it OSX?

Comment: Yes, when I used it, it gives me --help.

Comment: On OSX you can use `brew install grep` to instal `gnu-grep`

Comment: I tried that, and got `Error: No available formula for grep`. I believe your solution works, but I'd rather avoid system-level changes to make this work. Thanks for your help though. Hopefully others will find your answer useful.

Comment: This is not a system level change actually since this `grep` is installed in separate path `/usr/local` leaving system default `grep` unaffected.